# How do I eliminate outliers in pricing data?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, outliers

I'm currently working on a trading card game (TCG) pricing application. Its job is to collect data from different vendors and use that data to determine a market price for any given card. For the sake of example, let's consider a theoretical card X.

X has a variety of values depending on the vendor that is selling it. Here is an array of its values:

`[1.00, 1.10, 1.05, 0.95, 2.00, 0.10]`

These values refer to its dollar ($) value.

From my experience as a customer in this market, I'm assuming that pricing data is **normally distributed**. Pricing data tends to gravitate towards one price, with a lot of different vendors pricing their cards close to said price (to be competitive), with the occasional outlier.

Under these assumptions, how would I eliminate outliers in the above data set? At first glance, $2.00 and $0.10 appear to be outliers. But pricing fluctuates in the market. It's not uncommon for a card's value to spike and conversely tank.

I've researched some methods such as using a threshold of standard deviations from the mean (e.g. if a price is >2 standard deviations from the mean, consider it an outlier) or using the median absolute deviation, but I'm unsure what algorithm even makes sense in the context of what I'm working on.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to look for outliers based on sample mean and standard deviation, as both estimators are very sensitive to outliers.  It's better to use percentile based approaches.  The p-th percentile is a value such that p% of the data are ≤ that value and (100-p)% are ≥ that value.  The 25<sup>th</sup> and 75<sup>th</sup> percentiles, often denoted Q1 and Q3, respectively, are also known as the first and third quartiles.  Their difference Q3-Q1 is called the Inter-Quartile Range (IQR).

A commonly accepted statistical definition of outliers is that they are observations which fall outside the range [Q1 - 1.5·IQR, Q3 + 1.5·IQR].  See [statisticshowto.com](http://www.statisticshowto.com/find-outliers/) or the [Wikipedia quartile article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) for more info.

One complication is that there are differing opinions about how to determine Q1 and Q3.  Some folks think it should be one of the actual observations, while others interpolate.  If you use [Statistics How To's IQR calculator](http://www.statisticshowto.com/calculators/interquartile-range-calculator/), both extremes of your data are outliers.  In [JMP](https://www.jmp.com/en_us/home.html), which uses interpolation, neither extreme is an outlier.  This is mostly an issue with sparse data.  With more data, the discrepancies between the two approaches disappear.

A real benefit of a percentile based solution is that it doesn't rely on distributional assumptions.  This approach works robustly regardless of whether your assumption of normality is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a deviation method, definitely use the median/median absolute deviation instead of the mean/standard deviation because that method is much less sensitive to exactly what the outliers are. You should experiment with the multiplier (e.g., outliers are three times further than the MAD) in the context of your specific application.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of algorithm should include some density estimate given your comment about the "price fluctuation". Therefore any measure of the *overall* median and quantiles should not be the last word on entries being outliers. They should be compared to their neighbors.

Here is some info on `Kernel Density` estimators

https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-kernel-density-approach-to-outlier-detection/

[image]